# How to validate that a string is a proper hexadecimal value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, hex

I am writing a 6502 assembler in Ruby.  I am looking for a way to validate hexadecimal operands in string form.  I understand that the String object provides a "hex" method to return a number, but here's a problem I run into:

```
  "0A".hex #=> 10 - a valid hexadecimal value
  "0Z".hex #=>  0 - invalid, produces a zero
"asfd".hex #=> 10 - Why 10?  I guess it reads 'a' first and stops at 's'?
```

You will get some  odd results by typing in a bunch of gibberish.  What I need is a way to first verify that the value is a legit hex string.

I was playing around with regular expressions, and realized I can do this:

```
true if "0A" =~ /[A-Fa-f0-9]/
#=> true

true if "0Z" =~ /[A-Fa-f0-9]/
#=> true <-- PROBLEM
```

I'm not sure how to address this issue.  I need to be able to verify that letters are only A-F and that if it is just numbers that is ok too.

I'm hoping to avoid spaghetti code, riddled with "if" statements.  I am hoping that someone could provide a "one-liner" or some form of elegent code.

Thanks!

Comment: Anchor your pattern with `^$` otherwise, the zero matches, and the `Z` does not need to match. `true if "0Z" =~ /^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$/`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!str[/\H/]` will look for invalid hex values.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a Binary equivalent to this?

Comment: This doesn't work on 1.8.7 and doesn't handle leading strings with "0x".  But still cool.

Comment: @AShelly No biggie: `!str.gsub('0x','')[/\H/]`

Answer (score 3):

`String#hex` does not interpret the whole string as hex, it extracts from the beginning of the string up to as far as it can be interpreted as hex. With `"0Z"`, the `"0"` is valid hex, so it interpreted that part. With `"asfd"`, the `"a"` is valid hex, so it interpreted that part.

Answer (score 2):

One method:

```
str.to_i(16).to_s(16) == str.downcase
```

Another:

```
str =~ /\A[a-f0-9]+\Z/i   # or simply /\A\h+\Z/ (see hirolau's answer)
```

About your regex, you have to use anchors (`\A` for begin of string and `\Z` for end of string) to say that you want the full string to match. Also, the `+` repeats the match for one or more characters.

Note that you could use `^` (begin of line) and `$` (end of line), but this would allow strings like `"something\n0A"` to pass.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just had the issue myself. I opted for this in my code:

`str =~ /^\h+$/`

It has the added benefit of returning nil if str is nil.

Answer (score -2):

Since Ruby has literal hex built-in, you can eval the string and rescue the SyntaxError

eval "0xA"   => 10

eval "0xZ" => SyntaxError

You can use this on a method like

```
def is_hex?(str)
  begin
    eval("0x#{str}")
    true
  rescue SyntaxError
    false
  end
end

is_hex?('0A') => true
is_hex?('0Z') => false
```

Of course since you are using eval, make sure you are sending only safe values to the methods

Comment: Good idea, but you have to tell how to do that given the strings that the OP provide.

Comment: Not sure why I got two negative, since I provided a perfectly valid answer there. Just to illustrate my point I will just add a method to the answer to see how it could be used

Comment: And obviously `1; "system \"rm -rf /\"; 5"` is a valid hex number. :)

Comment: well, in the example method I just provided, I am saying you must be careful when doing an eval. That goes without saying

Comment: It isn't a "bad" example, but I was hoping to find an elegant solution with minimal overhead.  Using 'eval' is a last resort in my experience.